# Getting the value from a button text for thyme leaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Ok, I have this somewhat complex piece of HTML that I have to integrate with.  It is a button with a drop down (using aria) and I had to pass in a currency list and be able to select one of the dropdown elements (currency values) and update the button text with the selected value.  I write a tiny bit of js and that works well.  I use thymeleaf to pass in values to populate and that works well.  I also need to read the values that were set from the post to the spring mvc controller but I always get a empty string for the value that I set via js.

here is the javascript

---

```
  $(".currencyDropdown li a").click(function () {
            var selText = $(this).text().trim();
            var button = $("#currencyButton");
            button.text(selText);
            console.log("currency selected is:" + selText);
        });
```

---

here is the html

---

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12 form-row">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle field-small"
                                type="button"
                                id="currencyButton"
                                name="currencyButton"
                                th:field="${pals.selectedCurrency}"
                                data-toggle="dropdown"
                                th:inline="text">
                            [[${pals.selectedCurrency}]]
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </button>
                        <ul id="currencyDropdown"
                            class="dropdown-menu currencyDropdown"
                            role="menu"
                            aria-labelledby="currencyButton">
                            <li role="presentation"
                                th:each="currency:${pals.currencyList}">
                                <a role="menuitem"
                                   tabindex="-1"
                                   href="#"
                                   th:inline="text">
                                    [[${currency}]]
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

---

What I am trying to read back in the spring mvc controller is the pals.selectedCurrency value and it is always empty. Something I am missing?  I was playing around and tried setting value and field.  In reality I want to read the inline text that my js inserts.

Comment: I am slightly confused, are you trying to make the text of the button equal to the selected value in the drop down. e.g. you select "Dollar" the button will show "Dollar"?

Comment: yes, that works fine and is what I wanted.  The problem that I am trying to figure out is how to read the set value for the button (in your example of setting the button text to "dollar") and reporting that is the backing bean that I have to to read what the button was set to.  It comes back as "".

Comment: Do you want to read value attribute of button element or text set for button element? You trying to read it on client side via javascript or are you trying to submit that to your controller on POST request?

Comment: The javascript is to set the text for the button.  Its spring mvc with thyme leaf tempting to pass the data values to the client side html.  The javascript is meant to set the button text value.  So I want to pass the value form the button text back via the backing bean that thyme leaf uses to the spring controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a relatively simple answer to it.  I have to use the html that was provided because of look and feel considerations from the customer.

so what I did was add a hidden input and set that from the java script.

---

```
$(".currencyDropdown li a").click(function () {
        var selText = $(this).text().trim();
        $("#currencyButton").text(selText);
        $("#currencySelected").val(selText);
        console.log("currency selected is:" + selText);
    });
```

---

```
<input type="hidden"
                               id="currencySelected"
                               th:field="${pals.selectedCurrency}"/>
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle field-small"
                                type="button"
                                id="currencyButton"
                                data-toggle="dropdown"
                                th:inline="text">
                            [[${pals.selectedCurrency}]]
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </button>
                        <ul id="currencyDropdown"
                            class="dropdown-menu currencyDropdown"
                            role="menu"
                            aria-labelledby="currencyButton">
                            <li role="presentation"
                                th:each="currency:${pals.currencyList}">
                                <a role="menuitem"
                                   tabindex="-1"
                                   href="#"
                                   th:inline="text">
                                    [[${currency}]]
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

---

I see the correct values that were selected for my dropdown on the spring mvc controller and now I can get on with the rest of the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add a th:fragment on you button and change the text of the button via ajax from backing bean from server, not from javascript. It's something like this :

```
<form th:action="@{/PersonEdit/save(contract=${param.contract})}" th:object="${personBean}" 
              method="POST" th:if="${param.contract != null}">
```

... other form components

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" 
                                       th:text="#{person.edit.policy.tfoms}"></label>

                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <select class="form-control" th:field="*{tfoms}" 
                                            onchange="loadInsuranceCompanies()">
                                        <option th:each="t : ${tfomses}" 
                                                    th:value="${t.uidtfoms}"  
                                                    th:text="${t.shortName}"
                                                    th:selected="${personBean.tfoms != null 
                                                    and personBean.tfoms.equals(t)}"></option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('insuranceCompany')} 
                                 ? 'form-group has-error' : 'form-group'">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" 
                                       th:text="#{person.edit.policy.ic}"></label>

                                <div class="col-sm-8" id="insuranceCompaniesContent">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="insuranceCompany" 
                                            name="insuranceCompany"  
                                            th:fragment="insuranceCompany">
                                        <option th:each="i : ${insuranceCompanies}" 
                                                    th:value="${i.uidinsurancecompany}"  
                                                    th:text="${i.shortName}"
                                                    th:selected="${personBean.insuranceCompany != null 
                                                    and personBean.insuranceCompany.equals(i)}"></option>
                                    </select>
                                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('insuranceCompany')}" 
                                         th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('insuranceCompany')}">
                                        <span class="text-danger" th:text="${err}"></span><br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

In my case I refreshing one dropdown via another.Then refresh this fragment via ajax on item selection

```
function loadInsuranceCompanies() {
                var url = [[@{/PersonEdit/insuranceCompanies}]];
                if ($('#tfoms').val() !== '') {
                    url = url + '/' + $('#tfoms').val();
                }
                $("#insuranceCompaniesContent").load(url);
            }
```

I think the trouble can be because you using not a standard select as a dropdown.